# Unexpected table output in Lotus with HTML/CSS in a rails app

Tags: html, css, lotus

I'm generating HTML tables that are meant to be sent via Lotus Notes (8.0.2) with my rails app.

My tables are extremly simple (have a look at this fiddle) : [Example output](http://jsfiddle.net/msbkk/) and render correctly into jsfiddle or into my browser.

Here is a reduced HTML code :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Example</th>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class='name'>Foo</td>
            <td class='number'>11</td>
            <td class='number'>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='name'>Bar</td>
            <td class='number'>8</td>
            <td class='number'>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class='name'>Baz</td>
            <td class='number'>4</td>
            <td class='number'>-12</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**My problem** : The output I get in Lotus Notes is broken. My table cells are too small and don't adapt to content's length. For example, the word 'Example' is broken like that :

```
Examp(new line)
le
```

Unfortunatly, I can't upload a screenshot because my company is monitoring the uploads...

When I remove this CSS :

```
th, td, tr, table {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

the problem disapears **but** I don't have my mandatory borders anymore!

I think Lotus might be using a very old version of html/css interpreter. Do you know how I can bypass this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

### Edit :

I duct-taped the problem by adding some `&nbsp;` into the `th` elements. But this is far from an elegant solution...

Comment: try adding padding to the <th> elements.

Comment: @vishalkin The output is the same (yes, it's strange)

Comment: If it's a very old HTML parser, maybe you could try adding `border="1"` to the table start tag instead of using the css.

Comment: @MrLister Tried it but... nope :(

Comment: Sorry, just guessing; I don't have Lotus Notes here... As a last resort, you could try setting a width to the table cells explicitly: `<th width="60">` or something. But of course that would depend on the content and the font.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent upon whether you're outputting the HTML via a Form, Agent, or some other mechanism, additional "junk" may be getting injected.

The cleanest way I've found is to have an Agent print out the HTML directly. Other design elements often generate too much additional code.